# Check if some game is currently running and on top

Tags: python

I am creating a keybind program for one game. So far it works perfectly but I constantly minimize this game to IM or do something else. So.. How do I make my program work when I got this game on top and when the game is minimized the program shouldn't work.

Comment: Depends on your definition of "on top."  User could have multiple monitors where the game window and some other application window don't overlap.

Comment: I want this program to work only when I'm playing this game, so if I have this game minimized or it's not even running the program should stop working and when I start playing the game again my program should start working again. How do I do that ?

Comment: Can you please Include some code?

Comment: I answered, but that is an old article using C# back when .NET 2.0 just was coming out (maybe even 1.1).  What language are you writing your app in?

Comment: http://paste.pocoo.org/show/229968/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're talking about the app that currently has the focus (like, WOW when it is full screen and you're playing, for example), then you should check out [this tutorial](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/satisharveti/ActiveApplicationWatcher01252007024921AM/ActiveApplicationWatcher.aspx).  It's a tutorial on how to build an app that keeps track of what applications have been actively used.  In the tutorial it explains how to use "user32.dll" to get the title of the active window.  You could then, in your app, just check to see if the active title is the app that you want to have your app function or not, and then proceed or cancel accordingly.